# Recursively add element to array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need to merge those two arrays (`$array2` in `$array1`):

```
$array1 = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value1', 'value1_1'),
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value10', 'value10_1'),
                'key3' => 'value30',
            ),
        ),
        ...
    ),
);

$array2 = array(
    'data' => array(
       array(
           'raw' => array(
               'key1' => 'value1_2',
               'key2' => 'value2',
           )
       )
    )
);
```

Expected result :

```
array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value1', 'value1_1', 'value1_2'),
                'key2' => 'value2',
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value10', 'value10_1'),
                'key3' => 'value30',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

When I'm using [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to merge `$array2` in `$array1['data'][0]`, I've got the following result:

```
$array1 = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value1', 'value1_1'),
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value10', 'value10_1'),
                'key3' => 'value30',
            ),
        ),
        array(
           'raw' => array(
               'key1' => 'value1_2',
               'key2' => 'value2',
           )
       )
    ),
);
```

When I'm using [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php), I've got the following result:

```
$array1 = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => 'value1_2',
                'key2' => 'value2',
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'raw' => array(
                'key1' => array('value10', 'value10_1'),
                'key3' => 'value30',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

I'm looking for the simplest way to get the expected result.
The arrays can have an unknown deph data structure and it can have more than one indexed subarray. It seems I need a combinaison between `array_merge_recursive` and `array_replace_recursive`

Thanks a lot for your answers :)

Comment: Do you _NEED_ recursion?  Is your data structure of unknown depth? Might the `data` subarray have more than one indexed subarray? If not, then I would argue that you should change your structure. ...Indexed arrays can really foul things up sometimes.

Comment: Yes it is an unknow deph data structure. Indeed, the array can have more than one indexed subarray.... I will edit my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: Please provide sample input that clarifies the complexity of your data.  Also, post your actual/complete/best coding attempt so that this isn't closed as Too Broad.

Comment: I edited my answer. Tell me if you need more info. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needing a bit of preparation first, to weed out that unwanted indexed subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6qBPf))

```
$array1['data']=current($array1['data']); // repair
$array2['data']=current($array2['data']); // repair
var_export(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));  // merge as intended
```

Output:

```
array (
  'data' => 
  array (
    'raw' => 
    array (
      'key1' => 
      array (
        0 => 'value1',
        1 => 'value1_1',
        2 => 'value1_2',
      ),
      'key3' => 'value3',
      'key2' => 'value2',
    ),
  ),
)
```

After question update to express a more complex data structure...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BMVa7))

```
foreach ($array1['data'] as $set) {
    foreach ($set['raw'] as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($result['data']['raw'][$k])) {
            $result['data']['raw'][$k] = $v;
        }else {
            $result['data']['raw'][$k] = array_merge((array)$result['data']['raw'][$k],(array)$v);
        }
    }
}
foreach ($array2['data'] as $set) {
    foreach ($set['raw'] as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($result['data']['raw'][$k])) {
            $result['data']['raw'][$k] = $v;
        }else{
            $result['data']['raw'][$k] = array_merge((array)$result['data']['raw'][$k],(array)$v);
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: this is only okay for the **specific** sample data, I suspect the aswer should be more robust

Comment: Sure.  I hope the OP clarifies.  I can only build a solution for what is provided.  Otherwise it is a rabbit hole of possibilities and fringe cases.

Comment: @BwaBwa Please check my new snippet on your actual project data and let me know if it breaks.  ...and if it does, please offer a minimal input array that causes the issue and I'll try again.

Comment: @mickmackusa Wow it works as expected ! I knew that will not be simple. Big thanks !!
If I find a simplest way; I will edit your answer :)